# What is the category of the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the category of the following differential equation:

$dx(t)=(x(f(t)),t)$ with $f:A \rightarrow B \quad A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

For $f$ linear, it belongs to to the category of pantograph differential equations which itself belongs to the category of delay differential equations if I understand it right.

But what if $f$ is nonlinear?

An example:

$dx(t)=x(t^2-2t+1)$.

Is it a delay differential equation, a nonlinear differential equation?
Are there any work in this category of differential equations?

Comment: What is the meaning of $dx(t)$ ?  And  what is the meaning of $x(t^2-2t+1)$ ? If $dx(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and if $x(t^2-2t+1)$ means $x$ multiplied by $(x^2-2t+1)$, but NOT $x$ function of $(x^2-2t+1)$, the ODE is a separable ODE very easy to solve.

Comment: No, it should not be a multiplication $x \cdot (t^2-2t-1)$, here $x$ is a function of $t$

Comment: OK. It's clear.